# How to decode the access token returned by the Skype for Business service

Tags: decode, access-token, skype-for-business, cbor

According to [Skype for Business Authentication]
https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/GettingStarted-Authentication, we can obtain the oauth access token via the oauth service. The access token looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
{
  "access_token":"cwt=2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA...",
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "expires_in":3600
}
```

I wonder if the access token is indeed a CBOR Web Token (CWT), and if yes, how to decode the token using python or any language.

Comment: You might consider changing your question or asking a new question of simply, "how can I decode CBOR Web Tokens in [language]".

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean how to decode? A CBOR Web Token is an easily read format.

See the RFC and specifically the example here:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8392#appendix-A.3

Taking the CWT byte string:

```
d28443a10126a104524173796d6d657472696345434453413235365850a70175636f61703a2f2f61732e6578616d706c652e636f6d02656572696b77037818636f61703a2f2f6c696768742e6578616d706c652e636f6d041a5612aeb0051a5610d9f0061a5610d9f007420b7158405427c1ff28d23fbad1f29c4c7c6a555e601d6fa29f9179bc3d7438bacaca5acd08c8d4d4f96131680c429a01f85951ecee743a52b9b63632c57209120e1c9e30
```

And putting it through the CBOR playground at http://CBOR.me gives:

```
D2                                      # tag(18)
   84                                   # array(4)
      43                                # bytes(3)
         A10126
      A1                                # map(1)
         04                             # unsigned(4)
         52                             # bytes(18)
            4173796D6D65747269634543445341323536
      58 50                             # bytes(80)
         A70175636F61703A2F2F61732E6578616D706C652E636F6D02656572696B77037818636F61703A2F2F6C696768742E6578616D706C652E636F6D041A5612AEB0051A5610D9F0061A5610D9F007420B71 
      58 40                             # bytes(64)
         5427C1FF28D23FBAD1F29C4C7C6A555E601D6FA29F9179BC3D7438BACACA5ACD08C8D4D4F96131680C429A01F85951ECEE743A52B9B63632C57209120E1C9E30
```

*One quick note about using the CBOR playground at CBOR.me, it does not format cartridge returns or tabs correctly sometimes. It can do some weird things like drop a nibble from the middle of the hex bytes, crazy. So remove any formatting before pasting.*

Which is what the RFC shows as the decoded value. (Note, you will lose whitespace formatting when decoding CBOR)

```
18(
     [
       / protected / << {
         / alg / 1: -7 / ECDSA 256 /
       } >>,
       / unprotected / {
         / kid / 4: h'4173796d6d657472696345434453413
                      23536' / 'AsymmetricECDSA256' /
       },
       / payload / << {
         / iss / 1: "coap://as.example.com",
         / sub / 2: "erikw",
         / aud / 3: "coap://light.example.com",
         / exp / 4: 1444064944,
         / nbf / 5: 1443944944,
         / iat / 6: 1443944944,
         / cti / 7: h'0b71'
       } >>,
       / signature / h'5427c1ff28d23fbad1f29c4c7c6a555e601d6fa29f
                       9179bc3d7438bacaca5acd08c8d4d4f96131680c42
                       9a01f85951ecee743a52b9b63632c57209120e1c9e
                       30'
     ]
   )
```

Now, on the CBOR COSE/CWT format itself.

The 5 second breakdown is this:

CWT is an outer CBOR array of 4 items [

- [Item 0] - Protected Section. A CBOR encoded byte string. With claims for the payload, such as which encryption or signing is used. This section is calculated with the signature and thus can not be changed by a third party.
- Item 1 - Unprotected Section. A CBOR map. This contains other claims, typically encryption related helpful data for you to use to make sense of the payload. You can add your own data here as well. This section is not brought in when the signature is calculated, thus the name "unprotected".
- [Item 2] - Payload. A CBOR encoded byte string. This is the section you're most interested in. On a signed message this is ofcourse brought in when calculating the signature. For an encrypted message this will be the only encrypted portion. Likely padded. Note that some decoders may handle extra bytes / padding differently than others.
- [Item 3] - Signature. A CBOR encoded byte string. This is the signature for protected+payload sections.

] end

A couple of notes:

**1.** If you were paying attention you noticed that a CBOR CWT is a CBOR box, and inside it a byte string, a map, a byte string, and byte string where all byte strings are separate CBOR encoded maps. Not in a logical order of putting the actual map first or last. You "just" need to know that we're going to open this, decode the first CBOR byte string that means Protected which is a CBOR map itself with special key/value pairs (see Note #3), then the unprotected MAP with it's claims, two more CBOR strings that mean Payload and Signature, and because JOSE/JWT/COSE/CWT allow any number of encryption and signing formats, you'll need to examine the protected and unprotected sections before you have enough information to verify the signature. This is all on you to remember. Do you consider a format to be "good" if you need to "just know" how to interpret it? I believe this to be very opposite to JSON and even JWT that despite being human readable are just logically laid out. I consider CWT to be a fairly high entropy format if you aren't used to the data. Yours is the first real world application of CWT I've seen, I don't expect to see many more.

**2.** COSE / CWT spec recommends using "application/cwt" so when you receive some packet of bytes you know it's a CWT. Fine, but, in your case above you have "cwt=[some cwt]" which means to decode you would need to strip "cwt=" and then convert from BASE64 to HEX then decode as above. I hope whoever did this understands just how incorrectly they're applying the protocol any gains by using a binary format like CBOR were lost when representing in BASE64 which is 50% larger than binary for the same representation. By using "application/cwt" you would only need to present the hex string. In the example they're including application claims outside of the CWT.

**3.** COSE and CWT use tags and header references to short hand imply values. Using the letters "kid" for Key Identification would encode using 4 bytes for the name of that map/object. [string len 3, k, i, d] so they use references to "be more efficient". In this case they use integer 2, where 2 = . This means the "name" portion of the map is one byte. *Note that CBOR allows you to assign a number to a value in a map, JSON does not, converting CBOR/CWT to JSON/JWT would be tedious for this reason.* Read the RFC and check the aliases. This is in effect taking the schema-less CBOR and applying a layer of schema to it. I'm working on an embedded application with CBOR data in and out, and I'd much rather spend the 2-4 bytes per map to have "i" or "iss" than to just "have to remember" and get my other developers to all know that value 1 in the protected section is ALGORITHM but value 1 can also mean ISSUER in another section. Perhaps if you're going to take a schemaless format and apply a schema to it, you could just start with the schema format that is applied consistently? Time will tell if CWT's approach becomes popular among IoT and other constrained devices.

**4.** I don't have enough of your example to decode. But the BASE64 you posted starts with 0xD9 0x8A 0x2D ... which is a valid CBOR item meaning TAG 0x8A2D. However, it is very questionable as it would be a tag in the unassigned region, TAG 35373. If this is a real example I could only at this point guess that the user is trying to poorly obfuscate some intention by using standards in a non-standard way. A real CWT should use tag 16, 17, 18, or 61 typically. See this link for CBOR assigned tags, http://cbor.schmorp.de/stringref ... EDIT: Just saw this is a Skype for Business token!? Well, it's probably not obfuscation, but I really couldn't guess why they're seemingly making up alternatives to things the standard provides.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late, but since this topic comes what when you search the web, I wanted to chime in.  The CWT returned by Skype for Business Authentication (MS RTC Authentication) is not a CBOR Web Token.  It appears to be a much older technology, called a Compact Web Ticket.  I am not aware of a way to parse the contents of these strings, but it's not as a JSON Web Token nor as a CBOR Web Token.

Comment: This makes sense. So while I’ve seen COSE in the wild (OSCORE, end to end CoAP). I still haven’t seen CWT.